# Convert HTML to R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there a way to convert an html file, such as https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidytext/vignettes/tidytext.html, and convert it to an executable R Markdown file (rmd)?

Comment: seems possible but difficult.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: where's it gonna get the data from?

Comment: I've made an answer below using visual markdown editor in RStudio (v1.4+), which makes the occasional conversion very easy.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution I use:

- convert .html to .md :

```
pandoc ./test.html -o test.md
```

- rename .md to .rmd

```
mv test.md test.rmd
```

- post-process the code to organize chunk and paragraphs

```
# chunks r marker: replace ' {\.sourceCode \.r}' by '{r}'
sed -i 's/ {\.sourceCode \.r/{r/' test.rmd
# delete lines beginning wit ':::'
sed -i '/^:::/d' test.rmd
# delete lines beginning '![](data:image' (html plot)
sed -i '/^\!\[\](data:image/d' test.rmd
# delete paragraph separator lines
sed -i '/^=====/d' test.rmd
sed -i '/^-----/d' test.rmd
# replace paragraph marks
#'[1]{.header-section-number}' by '#'
sed -i 's/\[[0-9]\+\]{\.header-section-number}/#/' test.rmd
#'[1.1]{.header-section-number}' by '##'
sed -i 's/\[[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\]{\.header-section-number}/##/' test.rmd
#'[1.1.1]{.header-section-number}' by '###'
sed -i 's/\[[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\\.[0-9]\+]{\.header-section-number}/###/' test.rmd
```

- add YAML header

```
echo "$(echo -e "\n" | cat - test.rmd)" > test.rmd
echo "$(echo '---' | cat - test.rmd)" > test.rmd
echo "$(echo 'title: '\"'test'\" | cat - test.rmd)" > test.rmd
echo "$(echo '---' | cat - test.rmd)" > test.rmd
```

Of course you can have these lines in a .sh to simplify the task

Answer (score 5):

If a markdown file (`.md`) is sufficient then download and install `pandoc` if you don't already have it. Then run this from the commmand line or use `system("pandoc ...")` or `shell("pandoc ...")` from within R.

```
pandoc https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidytext/vignettes/tidytext.html -o out.md
```

For a particular file, it would be possible to post-process the source code and output sections but would represent some additional effort, possibly substantial.

Comment: Markdown looks *alright*, but lacks the full executability of an rmd file

Answer (score 5):

In short, no.

The [`pandoc`](http://pandoc.org/) binary is almost pure awesomeness, and I use it eg to convert the `html` output from an `Rd` file back into markdown (to be included in other markdown documents).

But that uses [`pandoc`](http://pandoc.org/) for what it knows: convert from markdown to html etc.  [`pandoc`](http://pandoc.org/) itself knows nothing about R.  So apart from the metaphysical difficulty of getting the *code* back from the *output* it created, you have a tool mismatch.

So in some: you probably want the original source code as you *cannot* recreate Rmd from the html output it produces.

Answer (score 5):

You can get a 98% result by:

1. Opening a new rmarkdown file (in RStudio v 1.4+),
2. Click on the "Switch to visual markdown editor" button*,
3. Select and copy the html output from the browser
4. Paste into your rmarkdown file.

To get the last 2%, you will want ensure R code chunks are recognised:

5. Click on the "Switch to source editor" button (same button as above).
6. Find and replace `<!-- -->` with   ```` ```{r} ```` and after finish the code chunks with  ```` ``` ````

And ensure data is available as required by the code. Good luck!

*To switch into visual mode for a markdown document, use the  button with the compass icon at the top-right of the editor toolbar - described here: https://blog.rstudio.com/2020/09/30/rstudio-v1-4-preview-visual-markdown-editing/

Comment: Saved me. Lost data frames when server went down but had a backup of the html file. Thank you.

Comment: This is by far the easiest solution! Amazing!

Answer (score 1):

```r
:~$ ## convert .html to .md :
:~$ pandoc Assessment-Week2B.html -o Assessment-Week2B.md
:~$ 
:~$ ## rename .md to .rmd
:~$ mv Assessment-Week2B.md Assessment-Week2B.rmd
:~$ 
:~$ ## edit via RStudio
:~$ rstudio Assessment-Week2B.Rmd
```

Tried to modify via terminal as below short MV, but modify via RStudio will be easier.

- [Convert HTML to R Markdown (Part 1)](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/3888890?key=8960446e7cf14a7f7e57654119a12679)
- [Convert HTML to R Markdown (Part 2)](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/3888975?key=942039826926a33aa7be69f0171f511b)