# How to group columns in R markdown?

Tags: markdown, knitr, pandoc, kable, kableextra

I am trying to generate a table using kable and saving the output as a markdown. I am later using pandoc to convert markdown to pdf. For my table I would like to group my table columns into two groups.  It seems that this could be achieved using the kableExtra "add_header_above" function, but unfortunately the output cannot be stored as markdown. Is there a way to group columns using markdown? I am pasting my dummy code below. Appreciate all comments and suggestions.

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
test <- head(mtcars, head=10)
test <- test[,c(1:6)]
kable(test, "markdown")
```

I have tried grouping the columns like below but it doesn't seem to work.

```
       |                  |     GroupA     |      GroupB     |
       |:-----------------|:---------------|:----------------|
       |                  |  mpg| cyl| disp|  hp| drat|    wt|
       |:-----------------|----:|---:|----:|---:|----:|-----:|
       |Mazda RX4         | 21.0|   6|  160| 110| 3.90| 2.620|
       |Mazda RX4 Wag     | 21.0|   6|  160| 110| 3.90| 2.875|
       |Datsun 710        | 22.8|   4|  108|  93| 3.85| 2.320|
       |Hornet 4 Drive    | 21.4|   6|  258| 110| 3.08| 3.215|
       |Hornet Sportabout | 18.7|   8|  360| 175| 3.15| 3.440|
       |Valiant           | 18.1|   6|  225| 105| 2.76| 3.460|
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you store the output in markdown and then `later using pandoc to convert markdown to pdf.` Why not in one step?

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

test <- head(mtcars, head = 10)
test <- test[, c(1:6)]

p <- kable(test) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Group 1" = 3, "Group 2" = 3))
p
```

According to your chosen output, you would get a table with grouped headings in "HTML" or "PDF" output.

You could use `p` to store the "HTML" output and use the `pandoc` binary to convert it to markdown. But the binary

> `pandoc` itself knows nothing about R. So apart from the metaphysical difficulty of getting the code back from the output it created, you have a tool mismatch.

(Quote from [Dirk Edelbuettel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336628/convert-html-to-r-markdown))

If you use the direct conversion to PDF you wouldn't need `p`.