# Getting R-Markdown (RMD) file for a given ggplot2 tutorial

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I've been looking for ggplot2 tutorials and found a couple of good ones such as [this one](http://r-statistics.co/Complete-Ggplot2-Tutorial-Part1-With-R-Code.html).

I'd have thought the easiest way to follow those would be if they come in R-Markdown (notebook) format, as I could then run & play with bits of code and observe the change in the plots.

However, none of the tutorials I found actually provide the RDM, and authors (undersandably) typically do not reply to requests to make those available.

There seem to be no (good) back-converters from HTML to RDM.

Before accepting I will just manually copy&paste bits of code into my R window and keep Alt-Tab'ing between that and the tutorial webpage/PDF, I just want to see if there is a way I've not realised yet to actually obtain the RDMs that must have been used to give rise to many of those HTML/PDF-format tutorials, when those are not provided.

Alternatively, is there a source of ggplot tutorials where RDMs *are* available?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert HTML to R Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336628/convert-html-to-r-markdown)

Comment: Afraid it doesn't. Sorry, forgot to mention that I tried that, and (as the answers in that other question suggest) the outputs are disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

There are several tutorials and books that do this. Here’s mine:

https://socviz.co

Information on the package that accompanies the book can be found at

https://kjhealy.github.io/socviz

You can install it from GitHub or CRAN. It includes a course packet with an Rmd file containing the code for the figures in each chapter.

Comment: Thanks Kieran. Is there a payment required at some point in order to follow through the package and learn ggplot by changing the code in the RMarkdown ?

Comment: No. Like I said, the package is available on GitHub and CRAN.

Comment: Ah yes, of course, sorry... thanks again, look forward to doing this tutorial!