# Convert html page to markdown using R

Tags: r, markdown

I would like to convert a html page to markdown. In python we could use the `markdownify` package like described [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-html-to-markdown-in-python/). Here is some reproducible code in python like described in the source:

```
import markdownify 
  
html = """   
         <h1> <strong>Geeks</strong> 
         for<br> 
         Geeks 
         </h1> 
        """
  
h = markdownify.markdownify(html, heading_style="ATX") 

print(h)
```

Output:

```
#  **Geeks** 
 for 
 Geeks
```

I would like to achieve the same but using R. I was only able to find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336628/convert-html-to-r-markdown) but this converts html to rmarkdown file but not markdown like in the output above. So I was wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to convert html to plain markdown using R?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that we can use the `pandoc_convert` function from the `rmarkdown` package to convert a html file (input.html) to markdown like this:

```r
library(rmarkdown)
pandoc_convert("input.html", "markdown")
# **Geeks** for Geeks
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>